# How to plot multiple line graphs in one graph from a function that generates 3 graphs in a single command?

Tags: r, plot, graph, lapply, time-frequency

I am using frequencyConnectedness package in which one function plotOverall genrates 3 graphs one after another on pressing enter to continue. I need to plot all three graphs into one graph. How to do this ?

For sample data kindly use the dataset "volatilities" which comes with frequencyConnectedness package.

```
 library(frequencyConnectedness)
data(volatilities)
        bounds=(pi+0.0001,pi/3,pi/10,0)  
    p=list(p = 4, type = "const")  
        ESTIMATE<- spilloverRollingBK12(volatilities, n.ahead = 100, no.corr = F, func_est = "VAR", params_est = p, window = 100, partition = bounds)

        plotOverall(ESTIMATE)
```

The above command generates three graphs .Basically it generates one graph for each bound as i have defined three bounds it gives three graphs . I need to plot them all in one graph . How to do this ?

Comment: Could you dput a few line of your data? `dput(DATA[1:10,]`

Comment: Sir , I have added sample data in code above . Kindly guide how to generate three graphs in one plot either using lapply or any other function.

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Sir kindly use dataset volatilities that comes with frequencyConnectedness package itself. I have updated it above. Kindly guide me how to plot the three lines in one plot (not vertical or horizontal separated plots).

Comment: Kindly suggest some answer .